# A dominant and equivariant morphism has its image locally closed

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Please, I really appreciated if anybody can help me with this question or suggest a book:

I want to proof that:

Let $X,Y$ be two $G$-algebraic varieties and $f:X\rightarrow Y$ an equivariant and dominant morphism. If G is connected then $f(X)$ is open in $\overline{f(X)}$.

Thank you all!

Comment: This is not true. Let $G$ be the trivial group. Let $f:X\to Y$ be a dominant morphism whose image is not open. This map is clearly equivariant, and $G$ is connected. [For instance, take the usual example $X:=\mathbb{A}^2\to \mathbb{A}^2=:Y$ given by $(x,y)\mapsto (x,xy)$. The image of this morphism is not open, but it is dense.]

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar Yes, you're right. But in the case where $ G $ is non-trivial? I'm actually interested in that case, maybe I should have put it in the question... Is the statement also false when $ G $ is non-trivial?

Comment: Yes the statement is also wrong in that case.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but could you give a short explanation or an example of why the statement is also false when G is non-trivial? I'll really appreciate that!

Comment: You can let $G$ act trivially on $X$ and $Y$. Then, $G$ acts faithfully on $G\times X$ as $g\cdot (h,x) = (gh,x)$ and $G$ also acts faithfully on $G\times Y$. Now, with $X\to Y$ as  in my above comment,  the morphism $G\times X \to G\times Y$ given by $(g,x)\mapsto (g,f(x))$ is a counterexample to your claim. (It is dominant and $G$-equivariant, but its image is still not open.)